# Is there a way to make sure target = _blank links open in foreground?

Tags: javascript, html

For some browsers (and depending on settings), links with target = "_blank" seems to open in the foreground, but for a lot of others it seems to open in the background.

In my case opening in the foreground is what a user intends when she/he clicks on the link, so it would be nice if there is a way to ensure that. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Vlad - does [Sérgio](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383868/sergio-carvalho)'s solution below fix it for you (it does for me)? If so it might be useful to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using window.focus() to bring the new window to the front. You may do it on the opened document, using jquery, with:

```
$(function() {
    window.focus();
});
```

or from the original document:

```
var newWindow = window.open(url);
window.setTimeout(function() { newWindow.focus(); }, 1000);
```

The setTimeout is needed to allow time for the window to be actually created by the browser. There may be a cleaner method to achieve this, but the setTimeout should do it.

Comment: I've made a bookmarklet users can drag into their favourites bar and use to essentially bookmark sites. My code uses ['window.open(...)'](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) but the resulting new window is immediately pushed behind the open instance of the browser from which the bookmarklet was clicked. Although I'm not using target="_blank" it is the same problem @Vlad states above and Sergio's JavaScript solution has fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make sure these links open in the foreground. This is something the browsers arrange and there is nothing you can change about it.

You could however open the link in the same window by leaving out the target attribute, that will ensure the people clicking the link get to see the page immediatly. In a way this is also 'nicer' since it leaves the choice of opening the link in a new window to the user itself.